# Ошибка CLR20r3 во время выполенния метода (привязка к TabControl) из кода C#,WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, clr

Сигнатура проблемы:

```
  Имя события проблемы: CLR20r3<br>
  Сигнатура проблемы 01:    borejournals.exe<br>
  Сигнатура проблемы 02:    1.0.0.0<br>
  Сигнатура проблемы 03:    54ed6277<br>
  Сигнатура проблемы 04:    BoreJournals<br>
  Сигнатура проблемы 05:    1.0.0.0<br>
  Сигнатура проблемы 06:    54ed6277<br>
  Сигнатура проблемы 07:    11b<br>
  Сигнатура проблемы 08:    238(изначально было 1f2)<br>
  Сигнатура проблемы 09:    System.NullReferenceException<br>
  Версия ОС:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4<br>
  Код языка:    1049<br>
  Дополнительные сведения 1:    0a9e<br>
  Дополнительные сведения 2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789<br>
  Дополнительные сведения 3:    0a9e<br>
  Дополнительные сведения 4:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789<br>
```

На одном ресурсе нашел информацию, о том что сигнатура проблемы 07 - код который можно найти в IL коде.
Метод в котором возникает ошибка

```
private void SampleBinding()
{
    LayerGroupBox.DataContext = _journalStruct.InfoBore[_idBore].SoilLayer[_idLayer];

    if (_journalStruct.InfoBore[_idBore].SoilLayer[_idLayer].SoilSample != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Count = "+_journalStruct.InfoBore[_idBore].SoilLayer[_idLayer].SoilSample.Count());
        if (_journalStruct.InfoBore[_idBore].SoilLayer[_idLayer].SoilSample.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Count > 0 try to add samples into tabcontrol");
            try
            {
                DataScrollViewer.DataContext = Analyzes; // проходит нормально

                SoilTabControl.ItemsSource = _journalStruct.InfoBore[_idBore].SoilLayer[_idLayer].SoilSample; //крашится
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Crash, error: "+ exception.Message + 
                    ", source: " + exception.Source+
                    ", site: " + exception.TargetSite);
            }
        }
    }

    InnerListView.ItemsSource = _journalStruct.InfoBore[_idBore].SoilLayer[_idLayer].SoilInner;
    SoilsNameComboBox.ItemsSource = _classifier.Soilses;
    SoilsCategoryComboBox.ItemsSource = _category;
    //DataScrollViewer.DataContext = Analyzes;    
}
```

Отлов Exception не происходит, 100% уверен что    `_journalStruct.InfoBore[_idBore].SoilLayer[_idLayer].SoilSample;` 
- не пустой.

Проблема возникает только на ПК без Visual Studio.
 
.Net Framework 4.0 и выше (на всех пк), проект строится под 4.0. 
Пробовал выносить все библиотеки какие есть в проекте - локально к exe файлу приложения, результата нет.. 
при том на приложение работает на всех компах где есть .net 4.0/4.5 но обязательно присутствует visual studio, так же на 2 других без студии однако непонятно почему...

В прошлом году приложение работало на любом ПК, изменения вносились в код не пересекающийся с данным куском кода.

прилагаю найденные строки из IL по номеру кода 238

```
IL_0226:  ldarg.2
IL_0227:  castclass  [PresentationFramework]System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox
IL_022c:  ldarg.0
IL_022d:  ldftn      instance void BoreJournals.Frames.JourEditWindow::CheckedAnalyzes_onCheck(object, class [PresentationCore]System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
IL_0233:  newobj     instance void [PresentationCore]System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler::.ctor(object, native int)
IL_0238:  callvirt   instance void [PresentationFramework]System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton::add_Checked(class [PresentationCore]System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler)
IL_023d:  nop
IL_023e:  ldarg.2
IL_023f:  castclass  [PresentationFramework]System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox
IL_0244:  ldarg.0
IL_0245:  ldftn      instance void BoreJournals.Frames.JourEditWindow::CheckedAnalyzes_onCheck(object, class [PresentationCore]System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
```

За код прошу по рукам не бить, писался до знания о MVVM, заранее спасибо всем кто сможет помочь!

UPD:

```
Message: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.;

Terminating: True; 

Exception obj: System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
   в BoreJournals.Frames.JourEditWindow.System.Windows.Markup.IStyleConnector.Connect(Int32 connectionId, Object target) в h:\Работа\BoreJournals\BoreJournals\Frames\JourEditWindow.xaml:строка 1307
   в System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
   в System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlObjectWriter objectWriter)
   в System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject container, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector styleConnector, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1 templatedNonFeChildrenField)
   в System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject container, List`1 affectedChildren)
   в System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)
   в System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1 templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)
   в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
   в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   в System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   в System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   в System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   в System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   в System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   в System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   в System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   в System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   в System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   в System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
   в System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
   в System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
   в System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   в System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
   в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   в MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   в System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   в System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   в System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   в MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   в MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   в System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   в MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   в MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   в MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   в System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   в System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   в System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   в System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   в System.Windows.Application.Run()
   в BoreJournals.App.Main() в h:\Работа\BoreJournals\BoreJournals\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:строка 0
```

Выходит, что ошибка в `Checked="CheckedAnalyzes_onCheck"                                            Unchecked="CheckedAnalyzes_onCheck"`
Сам шаблон

```
 <ListView
   MinHeight="400"
   MaxHeight="500"
   ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DataScrollViewer, Path=DataContext}"
   Margin="2"
   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <CheckBox
           Grid.Column="0"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           Checked="CheckedAnalyzes_onCheck"
           Unchecked="CheckedAnalyzes_onCheck"
           Margin="2">
           <CheckBox.IsChecked>
             <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SetCheckListViewConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
               <Binding Path="Analyze" />
               <Binding ElementName="DataDocPanel" Path="DataContext"/>
             </MultiBinding>
           </CheckBox.IsChecked>
         </CheckBox>
         <TextBlock 
           Name="Gnd"
           Grid.Column="1"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           Margin="2"
           Text="{Binding Path=Analyze, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
       </Grid>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

выходит что IL все же верно направил?

```
IL_0238:  callvirt   instance void [PresentationFramework]System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ToggleButton::add_Checked(class [PresentationCore]System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler)
```

Ну и собственно сам метод в котором происходит крах:

```
private void CheckedAnalyzes_onCheck(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (SoilTabControl == null) return;
            var index = SoilTabControl.SelectedIndex;
            if (sender == null) return;
            var cb = sender as CheckBox;
            if (cb == null) return;
            if (cb.DataContext == null) return;
            var item = (Analyzes) cb.DataContext;

            if (_journalStruct.InfoBore[_idBore].SoilLayer[_idLayer].SoilSample == null) return;

            var analyzes = _journalStruct.InfoBore[_idBore].SoilLayer[_idLayer].SoilSample[index].SampleAnalyzes ?? (_journalStruct.InfoBore[_idBore].SoilLayer[_idLayer].SoilSample[index].SampleAnalyzes =
                new ObservableCollection<Analyzes>());

            if (cb.IsChecked == true)
            {
                if (!(analyzes.Any(soilse => soilse.Analyze == item.Analyze)))
                {
                    analyzes.Add(item);
                }
                if (analyzes.Count == 0)
                {
                    analyzes.Add(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var analyze in analyzes.Where(soilse => soilse.Analyze == item.Analyze))
                {
                    analyzes.Remove(analyze);
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Исключение при загрузке лабораторных анализов : "+exception.Message, "Внимание", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
    }
```

Однако обернув все в try, catch ничего не получаю.. выходит что ошибка появляется при формировании шаблона в xaml?
 
Или проблема возникает из-за вложенности шаблонов, потому что у меня идет TabControl-> TabControl.Contenttemplate -> DataTemplate -> dockpanel -> dockpanel -> ListView -> ListView.ItemTemplate -> DataTemplate -> Grid -> CheckBox
Не могу понять как с этим бороться =/ ибо где-то работает, а где-то нет.

UPD 2: 
И действительно убрав

```
Checked="CheckedAnalyzes_onCheck"
Unchecked="CheckedAnalyzes_onCheck"
```

все отображается как нужно, но метод содержит важные действия в частности добавление отмеченных и удаление не отмеченных значений из списка в коллекции, проверяю на null все что можно, однако проблема не пропала =/

Comment: Не похоже, что приведенный вами IL код относится к этому методу. На это также указывает тот факт, что `NullReferenceException` не ловится в вашем кэтче -- значит, он возникает не там. 238 -- это смещение внутри метода, который падает. 11b -- это токен падающего метода. Подпишитесь на событие `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` и выведите куда-нибудь информацию об исключении (`e.ExceptionObject.ToString()`), чтобы увидеть нормальный стектрейс. Ну и нам его покажите :).

Comment: Подготовлю код сейчас, ну а пробовать буду завтра с утра, как получу доступ к пользовательскому ПК на котором есть возможность увидеть ошибку. Возможно крашится не прямо при передаче объекта в itemSource, но дальше этой строчки ничего не идет =(

Comment: @andreycha , обновил вопрос с выводом ExcepionObject, посмотрите, пожалуйста, если не сложно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Или проблема возникает из-за вложенности шаблонов, потому что у меня
>   идет TabControl-> TabControl.Contenttemplate -> DataTemplate ->
>   dockpanel -> dockpanel -> ListView -> ListView.ItemTemplate ->
>   DataTemplate -> Grid -> CheckBox

Похоже, что так. В .NET Framework 4.0 есть баг:

> - У вас есть Microsoft приложений платформа.NET Framework 4.0 на    Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF).
> - В приложении имеется один шаблон, который вложен в другой шаблон.
> - Внутреннее (вложенное) шаблон содержит элемент управления, который    задает стиль и события. Стиль ссылки на статический ресурс.
> - При запуске приложения WPF.
>
> В этом случае исключение NullReferenceException в методе
>   IStyleConnector.Connect и затем завершает работу приложения WPF.

Информацию об исправлении можной найти [на сайте Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2464222/ru).

---

В качестве воркэраунда можно попробовать переместить внутренний шаблон (`Grid` из `ListView.ItemTemplate`) в ресурсы внешнего шаблона.

---

По-хорошему вам нужно сделать две вещи:

1. Применить воркэраунд у себя (поскольку обновить существующих клиентов м.б. проблематично).
2. Включить в требования программы наличие установленного обновления.

---

Еще несколько англоязычных ссылок по теме:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/629bfcc5-2005-4947-a001-993524798b52/istyleconnectorconnect-nullreferenceexception-was-unhandled-in-datatamplate-framework-40?forum=wpf

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080286/markup-istyle-connector-connect-error-on-binding-in-wpf

Comment: Пока что помечу как ответ, увы если не смогу воспроизвести ошибку в виртуальные,то проверить смогу только в понедельник. 
@andreycha Большое спасибо за ответ! Решение выглядит вполне реальным, однако support.microsoft слишком часто стал выкидывать ссылки на отсутствующие архивные данные, в итоге исправления у них нет, но вариант с ресурсами мне кажется вполне приемлемым.